# How to Create an Interactive SIde-by-Side Map using JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx-2, javafx

I'm trying to create a JavaFx gui that displays 2 maps side by side. One map is of the city while the other is the same city's transportation system. The goal of this application is to do the following:

When the user clicks on a certain location in the the first map (Normal City Map) the second map (Trans Map) should be highlighted in the same exact location or corresponding location.

i have already created the interface where it displays both the same maps and was able to make the mouseEvent in order to extract the coordinates.

The question is, How can i make the 2nd map highlight the same location when clicked?
ِAlso, is it possible to add a Zoom Feature on the interface?

Here is the Code:

```
package hcimetromap;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author tharwat
 */
public class HciMetroMap extends Application {

   final int xDiff = 675;
   double x = 0;
   double y = 0;

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
    stage.setTitle("Baseline");


    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getStylesheets().add("mainClass.css");
    layout.getStyleClass().add("main-class");

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 1200, 1200);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(
      getClass().getResource("mainClass.css").toExternalForm()
    );

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.centerOnScreen();


    scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                //log mouse move to console, method listed below
                x = me.getX();
                y = me.getY();
                System.out.println("Mouse moved, x: " +x +", y: " + y);
            }
        });

    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Associated Css:

```
.main-class {
  -fx-background-image: url('TransMap.jpg'), url('map1.jpg');
  -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
  -fx-background-size: 50% 100%, 50% 100%;
  -fx-background-position: right , left ;
  -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 30, 0.5, 0, 0); 
  -fx-background-insets: 30;

}
```

Comment: Are the two images of the same dimensions?

Comment: @user yes both are the same image in this case